# action called after binding jsf

Tags: java, jsf, action, icefaces, backing-beans

I am using icefaces 1.8 ,spring and jsf 1.X :-

I have a submit button which calls a method in backing bean lets say:**submit()**

```
 public String submit()
{ 
 sets userSession.reset=true;
   --------

     }
```

and i have icefaces:dataTable which has value binding as follows:-

```
<dataTable binding="#{userSession.check}">
```

also 
    getCheck()
    {
     checks value of userSession.reset;
    }

now problem is - when a submit button is present ,binding takes place before action method and it does not bind to updated value i.e. userSession.check with reset value -> true;

/Is there a way to force binding after action method or to some how set reset=true before binding.

Comment: Its almost 2014 either use Icefaces 3 or Primefaces 4. I'd prefer you to use Primefaces 4.

Comment: Its a very big application and it will be pain in the ass to upgrade it :(

Comment: OH sorry to hear that.